# Is there a way to create a timelocked mulstisig wallet from bitcoin-cli

Tags: script, multi-signature, taproot

So, I read that with the new taproot upgrade, now there is a possibility to reduce the number of signatures necessary to create a valid transaction in a multisig wallet.

For example, create a 3-5 wallet that after 100,000 blocks "downgrades" to a 2-5.

Is this possible to do with bitcoin-cli now? Or do we have to wait until November?

If it is, how can I do it.

Thanks a lot and sorry for the noob question

Answer (score 0):

> So, I read that with the new taproot upgrade, now there is a possibility to reduce the number of signatures necessary to create a valid transaction in a multisig wallet.

That would be using [MuSig](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/musig/), a multisignature protocol that uses Schnorr signatures (included within the Taproot upgrade). [MuSig2](https://medium.com/blockstream/musig2-simple-two-round-schnorr-multisignatures-bf9582e99295) still needs to be standardized and probably won't be supported in Bitcoin Core in November 2021 when Taproot activates.

> For example, create a 3-5 wallet that after 100,000 blocks "downgrades" to a 2-5. Is this possible to do with bitcoin-cli now? Or do we have to wait until November?

You cannot create arbitrary scripts with bitcoin-cli today and won't be able to in November (I suspect). You can [create](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/93672/create-custom-script-from-bitcoind) the script yourself and import it into a wallet using `importmulti`. See Kalle Alm's [btcdeb](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/btcdeb) project or [Miniscript](http://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/) for constructing arbitrary scripts.

Comment: Even if you manage to create such a script and import it, you cannot do more than watch fixed addresses. Derivation of addresses and (cooperation on) signing with them requires actual wallet support, which will likely only appear if and when Miniscript gets integrated into Bitcoin Core.